# How do I select individual words of a camelized word in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

What is the shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA to move across or select individual words of a camelized word? Lets say I have aLongMultiWordVariableName, I want to be able to move the cursor to each word for editing or select parts of the variable.

Eclipse has a shortcut to do this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> for move and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> for selection.

Comment: Surely I am not the only one that read "caramelized" ? ;)

Comment: mmmmmm, caramelized words ...

Answer (score 206, accepted):

IDEA has the same keystrokes as Eclipse for camel-case words, but you have to have the CamelHumps option turned on (it's in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Use "CamelHumps" words )

Comment: Same accomplished with Ctrl+Shift+A -> "camelhumps" -> down arrow -> enter. Sounds more troublesome, but Action Search is very nice.

Comment: @andersoyvind Thanks for mentioning Ctrl+Shift+A!!! This must be the most powerful shortcut in the universe.

Comment: It is Editor -> General -> Smart Keys now (as in Intellij 14 on Mac os X as of Oct 22 2015).  As noted by romaintaz, this setting must be combined with turning off "Honor CamelHumps words settings when selecting on double click", which can be found under "Settings -> Editor -> General" the mouse section.

Answer (score 124):

Yes, the answer of yalestar is correct.
Settings > Editor > Smart keys > Use "CamelHumps" words

However, here is something that can be usefull to know:
If you want to be able to select the whole word by double-click on it, unselect the "Honor 'CamelHumps' words settings when selecting on double click" in Settings > Editor.

Comment: The mouse setting is quite useful when navigating and selecting  code in remote sessions.

Comment: Update (Idea 15): "Use CamelHumps words" is in Editor>General>SnartKeys, "Honor CamelHumps ... on double click" is in Editor>General.

Comment: I was looking for this double-click-camelcase feature, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There is a shortcut in latest version of Android Studio. You can just tap "**Shift**" key twice(double click) and then in search type "camelhum" then the option will appear and you can toggle it on/off. I have attached an image for reference.[image]

Comment: up for the screen cap

Comment: thanks! It is helpful in case you would like to double click on a word to select whole with CamelHump turned on.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2022 when using Rider 2022.2.3 you go to **Settings** then under the **Keymap** section, you can search for *camelhump* to see the actions and their shortcuts:

[image: Settings window, Keymap section]

In my case I could already use Alt+Left/Right to navigate between sub-words, but I had to define custom shortcuts to do that while selecting the sub-words. You can set the shortcut by right-clicking one of the actions and choosing *Add Keyboard Shortcut*:

[image: Context menu for setting keyboard shortcut]

Comment: This has been bugging me for ages! Now I can finally leave camel humps ON while still having the ability to select an entire word, which is immensely useful when editing in multi-selection mode! Thanks, you made my day!