# How to navigate through the source code by parts in CamelCase (instead of whole words)?

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation, pycharm, camelcasing

I remember when I was using Eclipse that when holding CTRL and using left or right arrows Eclipse would navigate over the `LongCamelCaseWrittenWord` in several steps. One camel case word at time.

So it will go like follows (pipe `|` represents the actual cursor position):

```
|LongCamelCaseWrittenWord -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
Long|CamelCaseWrittenWord -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
LongCamel|CaseWrittenWord -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
LongCamelCase|WrittenWord -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
LongCamelCaseWritten|Word -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
LongCamelCaseWrittenWord|
```

Is there a way how to achieve this in IntelliJ? Currently IntelliJ steps over the whole word at once.

Using IntelliJ 9.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select individual words of a camelized word in IntelliJ IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411240/how-do-i-select-individual-words-of-a-camelized-word-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 415, accepted):

Yes, enable **Use "CamelHumps" words** in `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys`.

Comment: CamelHumps makes Ctrl+Right, Ctrl+Left jump by camel humps. 

How can I still have both functionalities, i.e. jump by words and by CamelHumps with different keys?

Comment: in the latest Idea the flow is `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys`

Comment: As @mafonya mentions in a different answer, the behavior for double-clicking can be restored by locating and disabling the setting called "Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click".

Comment: In case anyone else missed it, the 'Honor "CamelHumps"...' setting is in `Settings | Editor | General`

Comment: I agree that this should be the default behavior. For anyone coming from Eclipse this is like built into our muscle memory from day one.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+A type smartkeyscamel will allow to put it on straight away.

Comment: IDEA should enable this by default.

Comment: Changed my life.

Answer (score 50):

As answered elsewhere, you can enable **Use "CamelHumps" words** in `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys` to switch the shortcuts to work with camelCase instead of whole-word.

You can also access the previous behavior by assigning keyboard shortcuts to the appropriate actions under `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Keymap | Editor Actions`.  This image shows an example where I access the previous behavior by adding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>:

[image: keymap screenshot]

Comment: Awesome! This should be default behaviour in intellij!

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Double click does the whole word, but ctrl + direction uses came case.

Answer (score 25):

You can have both functionalities at the same time:

1. In "Settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys", disable "Use CamelHumps words".
2. In "keymap", create shortcuts for:

   - "Move caret to next word"
   - "Move caret to next word in different camelhumps mode"

Note that these steps correspond to IntelliJ 14, so they might be slightly different in other versions.

Comment: For curiosity, did you map both of them? If yes, which combination did you choose?

Comment: Yes, I mapped both, it is useful when you have long class names. In general, you don't want to have different shortcuts for every program. So, I used `ctrl+arrow` for whole words (that is the shortcut used *everywhere*), and `alt+arrow` for camelhumps words (that's the only remaining modifier, since shift is used for selection in every program)

Comment: I remapped that to `ctrl+PgUp/PgDn` and `Ctrl+(shift)+Tab`, since it is used in all browsers and most programs, so it is already in my muscle memory.

Comment: I'd like to use `alt+arrow` to move by entire words and `ctrl+arrow` to navigate by camel hump. (This is the default behavior in Xcode, which is my "muscle memory".) I'm trying to do this using IntelliJ's Preferences, but I can't get a simple `ctrl+{anything}` to register. `ctrl+alt+{something}` seems to work, as does `alt+{something}`, but not `ctrl+{something}`. I'm on a Mac. My current Keymap is Mac OS X 10.5+. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mbm29414: works fine for me on macos. even if it's already assigned to something else. maybe it's some setting external to intellij

Comment: @blue_note I got in touch with IntelliJ support and got it resolved. Not sure why, but it appeared that my installation was preventing me from using the `ctrl` key at all. Of course, I can't reproduce, and it could easily be a `ID10T` or `EBKAC` error. ;-)