# Changing behavior of Ctrl+Shift+Left/Right in IntelliJ IDEA like in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, usability, shortcut

Hi I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA and got here and there usability issues, because I'm coming from Eclipse.

When I rename a variable and want to mark the second part of it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, the cursor moves to the next word which is outside of the border for renaming and when I type the new name and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the rename isn't executed for the other usages of the variable. Is there a setting where it's possible to change the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> so that the caret moves right after the last character of the variable name?

#### Second question

When I'm moving the cursor through a variable name with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> the next stop in Eclipse was always before the next upper case letter. Is in Idea also a setting to activate this? This would be very helpful when renaming variables.

Comment: every can be configured through the File > Settings > Key Map, take a look at this post for the camel case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833544/can-intellij-navigate-through-the-source-code-by-camelcase-instead-of-whole-word

Comment: Thanks for the camel case hint, but why the heck destroys it marking a variable by double clicking on the name? Now just a party of the name is selected instead of the whole name. Why???

Comment: Ok, found it in the parent section: Honor "CamelHumps" word settings when selecting using double click should be disabled...

Comment: Placing two questions in one is discouraged in stackexchange. Please avoid this.  If you have two questions, post two questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate through the source code by parts in CamelCase (instead of whole words)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833544/how-to-navigate-through-the-source-code-by-parts-in-camelcase-instead-of-whole)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you exactly need is [I have jIdea 12.1]:

1. Go to settings [Ctrl+Alt+S]
2. Choose [Editor -> General -> Smartkeys]
3. Check the [Use "CamelHumps" Words] button

Вуаля!

Comment: As the side effect this makes the double-click select only the humps and not the whole word. To select whole word on double-clicking, go to Settings -> Editor and uncheck [Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click].

Comment: Editor -> General, at least on MacOS!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select `Keymap` from settings, you can change what you want it to there.

But I would suggest using the autocomplete/intellitext features of IntelliJ and the refactoring tool, without manually navigating through variable names - they normally get it right first time.