# How To Delete Keywords Separately by Capital Letters (Ctrl+Backspace) in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been using eclipse for a while, now I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. There was a good feature in Eclipse that I would like to use it in IntelliJ. Here is the feature:

This is my variable name: `int myVariableName;` when I use this (Ctrl+Backspace) shortcut end of the variable (Cursor is next to letter 'e') name variable becomes -> `int myVariable;` so it deletes until capital letter in eclipse. **(this is what I want, it deletes separately by capital letters)**

The issue in IntelliJ is that it deletes all variable names, so I need to re-write again. Where can I customize this setting?

Comment: Some additional information in the answers to [How to navigate through the source code by parts in CamelCase (instead of whole words)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833544/how-to-navigate-through-the-source-code-by-parts-in-camelcase-instead-of-whole)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ctrl+backspace deletes previous "word".

"word" can be defined as:

1. anything between two spaces (the default)
2. `camelCaseNotation`

The default is option (1). To change to option (2), go to `file->settings`, search `Smart Keys`, and check `Use "CamelHumps" words.`

As noted in comments below, this setting will also cause double-clicking to select only part of a camel-case word.  To restore double-click to select the whole word, uncheck Editor->General: `Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double-click.`

Comment: while this solves problem described in question, this is not an ideal solution. now when you double click a word, you will only select one CamelHump and there's no way to select the whole thing. e.g. thisIsMyVariable : when double clicking on "My" only "My" is selected and triple-click selects the whole row, and there's not way to select "thisIsMyVariable" - very disappointing

Comment: @Peter Perháč you can disable the setting 'Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click' under Settings | Editor | General. Then a double click select the whole variablename

Comment: They moved "Honor 'CamelHumps' under "Smart Keys" next to "Use 'CamelHumps'"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of toggling the `Use "CamelHumps" words` option under Settings -> Smart Keys, I prefer it to have a separate shortcut since I use them both in different situations.

Here is how I did it...

1. Go to Settings -> Keymap
2. Find the item called `Delete to word Start in Different "CamelHumps" Mode`
3. Add a shortcut for it. I picked `Ctrl + Backspace` on my MacOS keymap configuration.

So, whenever I need to delete a word by honoring the camel case (meaning that considering the words in camel case separately), I use `Ctrl + Backspace`. For other cases, I use the default `Opt + Backspace` shortcut.