# Is it possible to use "CamelHumps" option in Intellij/AS but having it select the whole name of field/method etc at double-click?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, customization

Not just the randomly clicked "hump", but the entire name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833544/can-intellij-navigate-through-the-source-code-by-camelcase-instead-of-whole-word

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's literally the very first option in Settings | Editor | General :)

```
[ ] Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click
```

Comment: It's a good thing you answered this question because I forget how to do it every single time I install Intellij!

Comment: Good answer, just be clear that you need to `uncheck` it, instead of check it. And IDEA should also make this default.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with @EricWang, Intellij should make CamelHumps option checked and Honor on double click unchecked by default.

Comment: This option is absent in Rider, omg. It sees to be a bug, you can change this setting via "Action" menu.. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__CamelHumps.html

Comment: Thanks @sinedsem :)

Comment: hahahaha, sry! :)

Comment: @sinedsem
You are my hero. It nearly drove me insane as I use both rider and idea. I still think this is a bug as this should option should be present in the settings.

Answer (score 4):

For those who did not find the option in IntelliJ here is

[image: IntelliJ option]